# Visualise most frequent words from a dataset of text in Python

Tags: nlp, data-visualization, visualization

I have a csv which contains year and text (transcript of a speech).

I have loaded it into a Dataframe and done with preprocessing.

Then, I have a new dataframe which contains the words and their frequency per year which looks like this,

[image]

The column "word" contains the original word. And the column like "1970" contains the frequency of that "word" occurred in the speech of that particular year. So, the "year" columns contain the frequency of words mentioned in the "word" column.

Now, I want to visualize the top five words spoken every year in a single plot. It can be any sort of visualization like scatter plots. All data in one figure with 2 axes, x-axis is year and y-axis is frequency and words next to the data points or in the legend.

Is there any way to do this in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `annotate` to add a label to a point. The rest is just plumbing e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

RANGE=(1970, 1974)
plt.xticks(range(*RANGE))
plt.xlim(RANGE)

def show(year, n=5):
    "Add the top-n words for a year to the current plot"
    top5 = df.nlargest(n, columns=str(year))
    plt.scatter([year]*n, top5[str(year)])
    for _,row in top5.iterrows():
        plt.annotate(row['word'], (year, row[str(year)]))

for year in range(*RANGE):
    show(year)
```

Comment: Thanks much. This makes so much sense. But I am getting a key error for this line : top5 = freqs_df.nlargest(n, columns=str(year)) .   KeyError: '1970'

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution. The key error was due to str(year) as year is a integer. I just removed str() and everything worked.

Comment: Is there anyway to change text annotations to hovering text ?